# How do I get specific text from excel worksheet using C#?

Tags: c#, office-interop

I'm wanting to find multiple cells where a string is present. So usually a cell will have a int and the next cell will have a string. Is there anyway to find the string and print the value(int) to the console. So column A would have int and column B would be string. If the int doesn't have a string then it doesn't get printed. I've tried a couple methods on here but can't find what I'm looking for.

```cs
    string fileExcel = @"C:\test.xlsx";
    Application x1Application = new Application();
    Workbook x1Workbook = x1Application.Workbooks.Open(fileExcel);
    Worksheet x1Worksheet = x1Workbook.ActiveSheet;
    var x1Range = (Excel.Range)x1Worksheet.Columns["A:B"];
```

Comment: Are you looking for help using Office Interop, or on the logic of how you would search for a string and print an int?

Comment: I'm using the Office Interop but anything would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Office interop isn't the most intuitive API, so you will need to be able to experiment quickly in a test environment to see what works and what doesn't work. Also, there are a lot of examples on MSDN for Office interop, and you will likely need to browse many examples to piece things together. The code below is mostly taken from [How to: Programmatically Search for Text in Worksheet Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-search-for-text-in-worksheet-ranges?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp)

In the test.xlsx file I have the following data

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | alpha |
| 2 | bravo |
| 3 | charlie |

```cs
string fileExcel = @"C:\test.xlsx";
var application = new Excel.Application();
var workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(fileExcel);
var worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
var range = (Excel.Range)worksheet.Columns["B:B"];
var foundRange = range.Find("bravo",
  Type.Missing,
  Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
  Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
  Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
  Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
  false,
  Type.Missing,
  Type.Missing);

if (foundRange != null)
{
    var numberRange = application.get_Range($"A{foundRange.Row}");
    Console.WriteLine(foundRange.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(numberRange.Value);
}
```

The above code should print

> bravo
> 2

Also note, that the above code is very bare bones just to help you get started. One of the reasons that the Office interop is difficult to work with is because things are so dynamic. Likely you will need a lot more null checks and type safety checks to make sure things are stable.